# How do I install linux on a laptop without AHCI support?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, intel-rst

I bought a new laptop (DELL p115g) that only has RST/Raid as options for the disk controller, no AHCI, and when I attempt to install either Solus or Ubuntu the disk is not detected, presumably due to a lack of support for RST, so I am unable to progress with installation. The disk is not listed in /dev/*, gparted or anywhere else.

Is there a way to install and then boot linux on this machine, perhaps by injecting the required driver into the installation medium like we used to have to for earlier versions of Windows and the AHCI drivers, or did I buy an expensive paperweight?

Comment: https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-uk/000131655/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-dell-pc?lwp=rt & https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/rq0rjk/cant_install_linux_without_changing_sata/ & 
https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Dell-M-2-FAQ-regarding-AHCI-vs-RAID-ON-Storage-Drivers-M-2-Lanes/td-p/5072571

Comment: https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-uk/000130987/how-to-install-the-ubuntu-operating-system-on-a-dell-optiplex-pc-with-raid

Comment: In the BIOS ensure that *General > Boot Sequence* is set to UEFI, that in *Advanced Boot Options* is disabled *Legacy Option ROMs*, and that *Secure Boot > Secure Boot Enable* is set to Disabled. Ensure also that the Linux installation media is of type UEFI.